# How to print the students name in this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

The concerned tables are as follows:

```
students(rollno, name, deptcode)
depts(deptcode, deptname)
course(crs_rollno, crs_name, marks)
```

The query is

*Find the name and roll number of the students from each department who obtained
highest total marks in their own department.*

Consider:

i) Courses of different department are different.

ii) All students of a particular department take same number and same courses.

Then only the query makes sense.

I wrote a successful query for displaying the maximum total marks by a student in each department.

```
select do.deptname, max(x.marks) from students so
inner join depts do
on do.deptcode=so.deptcode
inner join(
select s.name as name, d.deptname as deptname, sum(c.marks) as marks from students s
inner join crs_regd c
on s.rollno=c.crs_rollno
inner join depts d
on d.deptcode=s.deptcode
group by s.name,d.deptname) x
on x.name=so.name and x.deptname=do.deptname group by do.deptname;
```

But as mentioned I need to display the name as well. Accordingly if I include `so.name` in select list, I need to include it in `group by` clause and the output is as below:

```
Kendra Summers       Computer Science                     274
Stewart Robbins      English                              80
Cole Page            Computer Science                     250
Brian Steele         English                              83
```

expected output:

```
Kendra Summers       Computer Science                     274
Brian Steele         English                              83
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I do not understand the relation between courses and departments

Comment: @Sterconium course table contains the subject details (coursename), student roll no and his marks in that course. Depts table contains the name and deptcode of various departments.

Comment: Ok but I don't see how a course is related to a dept. I was expecting the course to have a foreing key poiting to dept.deptcode. But looking better I suspect that instead this is done via the students, I mean course.crs_rollno = students.rollno. Is that so?

Comment: @Sterconium yes, crs_rollno is referenced with students rollno and again students.deptcode is referenced with depts.deptcode. Sorry I should have mentioned it in the schema itself.

Comment: @APC lol. No not an assignment. I was solving these questions from a book for better understanding and there were 50 questions all based on this model. I could solve only half of them. I think I have to drop it for the time being. Though this community of SQL people helped me a lot in understanding.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.

Comment: (For the future--)This is a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem with a readable query I had to define a couple of views:

**total_marks**: *For each student the sum of their marks*

```
create view total_marks as select s.deptcode, s.name, s.rollno, sum(c.marks) as total from course c, students s where s.rollno = c.crs_rollno group by s.rollno;
```

**dept_max**: *For each department the highest total score by a single student of that department*

```
create view dept_max as select deptcode, max(total) max_total  from total_marks group by deptcode;
```

So I can get the desidered output with the query

```
select a.deptcode, a.rollno, a.name from total_marks a join dept_max b on a.deptcode = b.deptcode and a.total = b.max_total
```

If you don't want to use views you can replace their selects on the final query, which will result in this:

```
select a.deptcode, a.rollno, a.name 
from 
 (select s.deptcode, s.name, s.rollno, sum(c.marks) as total from course c, students s where s.rollno = c.crs_rollno group by s.rollno) a 
 join (select deptcode, max(total) max_total  from (select s.deptcode, s.name, s.rollno, sum(c.marks) as total from course c, students s where s.rollno = c.crs_rollno group by s.rollno) a_ group by deptcode) b 
    on a.deptcode = b.deptcode and a.total = b.max_total
```

Which I'm sure it is easily improvable in performance by someone more skilled then me...

If you (and anybody else) want to try it the way I did, here is the schema:

```
create table depts ( deptcode int primary key auto_increment, deptname varchar(20) );
create table students ( rollno int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(20) not null, deptcode int, foreign key (deptcode) references depts(deptcode) );
create table course ( crs_rollno int, crs_name varchar(20), marks int, foreign key (crs_rollno) references students(rollno) );
```

And here all the entries I inserted:

```
insert into depts (deptname) values ("Computer Science"),("Biology"),("Fine Arts");
insert into students (name,deptcode) values ("Turing",1),("Jobs",1),("Tanenbaum",1),("Darwin",2),("Mendel",2),("Bernard",2),("Picasso",3),("Monet",3),("Van Gogh",3);
insert into course (crs_rollno,crs_name,marks) values 
(1,"Algorithms",25),(1,"Database",28),(1,"Programming",29),(1,"Calculus",30),
(2,"Algorithms",24),(2,"Database",22),(2,"Programming",28),(2,"Calculus",19),
(3,"Algorithms",21),(3,"Database",27),(3,"Programming",23),(3,"Calculus",26), 
(4,"Zoology",22),(4,"Botanics",28),(4,"Chemistry",30),(4,"Anatomy",25),(4,"Pharmacology",27),
(5,"Zoology",29),(5,"Botanics",27),(5,"Chemistry",26),(5,"Anatomy",25),(5,"Pharmacology",24),
(6,"Zoology",18),(6,"Botanics",19),(6,"Chemistry",22),(6,"Anatomy",23),(6,"Pharmacology",24),
(7,"Sculpture",26),(7,"History",25),(7,"Painting",30),
(8,"Sculpture",29),(8,"History",24),(8,"Painting",30),
(9,"Sculpture",21),(9,"History",19),(9,"Painting",25) ;
```

Those inserts will load these data:

```
select * from depts;
+----------+------------------+
| deptcode | deptname         |
+----------+------------------+
|        1 | Computer Science |
|        2 | Biology          |
|        3 | Fine Arts        |
+----------+------------------+
select * from students;
+--------+-----------+----------+
| rollno | name      | deptcode |
+--------+-----------+----------+
|      1 | Turing    |        1 |
|      2 | Jobs      |        1 |
|      3 | Tanenbaum |        1 |
|      4 | Darwin    |        2 |
|      5 | Mendel    |        2 |
|      6 | Bernard   |        2 |
|      7 | Picasso   |        3 |
|      8 | Monet     |        3 |
|      9 | Van Gogh  |        3 |
+--------+-----------+----------+
select * from course;
+------------+--------------+-------+
| crs_rollno | crs_name     | marks |
+------------+--------------+-------+
|          1 | Algorithms   |    25 |
|          1 | Database     |    28 |
|          1 | Programming  |    29 |
|          1 | Calculus     |    30 |
|          2 | Algorithms   |    24 |
|          2 | Database     |    22 |
|          2 | Programming  |    28 |
|          2 | Calculus     |    19 |
|          3 | Algorithms   |    21 |
|          3 | Database     |    27 |
|          3 | Programming  |    23 |
|          3 | Calculus     |    26 |
|          4 | Zoology      |    22 |
|          4 | Botanics     |    28 |
|          4 | Chemistry    |    30 |
|          4 | Anatomy      |    25 |
|          4 | Pharmacology |    27 |
|          5 | Zoology      |    29 |
|          5 | Botanics     |    27 |
|          5 | Chemistry    |    26 |
|          5 | Anatomy      |    25 |
|          5 | Pharmacology |    24 |
|          6 | Zoology      |    18 |
|          6 | Botanics     |    19 |
|          6 | Chemistry    |    22 |
|          6 | Anatomy      |    23 |
|          6 | Pharmacology |    24 |
|          7 | Sculpture    |    26 |
|          7 | History      |    25 |
|          7 | Painting     |    30 |
|          8 | Sculpture    |    29 |
|          8 | History      |    24 |
|          8 | Painting     |    30 |
|          9 | Sculpture    |    21 |
|          9 | History      |    19 |
|          9 | Painting     |    25 |
+------------+--------------+-------+
```

I take chance to point out that this database is badly designed. This becomes evident with course table. For these reasons:

- The name is singular
- This table does not represent courses, but rather exams or scores
- crs_name should be a foreign key referencing the primary key of another table (that would actually represent the courses)
- There is no constrains to limit the marks to a range and to avoid a student to take twice the same exam
- I find more logical to associate courses to departments, instead of student to departments (this way also would make these queries easier)

I tell you this because I understood you are learning from a book, so unless the book at one point says "this database is poorly designed", do not take this exercise as example to design your own!

Anyway, if you manually resolve the query with my data you will come to this results:

```
+----------+--------+---------+
| deptcode | rollno | name    |
+----------+--------+---------+
|        1 |      1 | Turing  |
|        2 |      6 | Bernard |
|        3 |      8 | Monet   |
+----------+--------+---------+
```

As further reference, here the contents of the views I needed to define:

```
select * from total_marks;
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
| deptcode | name      | rollno | total |
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
|        1 | Turing    |      1 |   112 |
|        1 | Jobs      |      2 |    93 |
|        1 | Tanenbaum |      3 |    97 |
|        2 | Darwin    |      4 |   132 |
|        2 | Mendel    |      5 |   131 |
|        2 | Bernard   |      6 |   136 |
|        3 | Picasso   |      7 |    81 |
|        3 | Monet     |      8 |    83 |
|        3 | Van Gogh  |      9 |    65 |
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+

select *  from dept_max;
+----------+-----------+
| deptcode | max_total |
+----------+-----------+
|        1 |       112 |
|        2 |       136 |
|        3 |        83 |
+----------+-----------+
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. I also think that there should be a schema `course_offered(crs_code,offered_by, crs_name)` and the `course` schema here should be `course_registered(crs_cd, rollno, marks)` where `crs_cd ` should be referenced from `crs_code`.

Comment: But I wonder what measures can be taken to prevent a multiple entry of same student for the same course? I cannot make `rollno` column in `course_registered` unique.

Comment: Set the couple "crs_cd,rollno" as unique:
`ALTER TABLE course_registered ADD UNIQUE (crs_cd, rollno);`
(The precise form may vary from database driver)

Comment: The obvious interpretation is that crs_rollno is (a FK to) the rollno (enrollment number?) of a student who got marks in a course.  @Hamsa's code & comments confirm that. "Course" is a reasonable name the only table here with course data. The problem does not concern course departments & does concern student departments. "associate courses to departments" would "make these queries" impossible not "easier'' since we seek "students from each department". Constraints are not needed to query, only table meanings & the problem doesn't assume any. So... Your bullets are just unneeded complications.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this can be easily achieved if you use window function -

```
select name, deptname, marks
from (select s.name as name, d.deptname as deptname, sum(c.marks) as marks,
             row_number() over(partition by d.deptname order by sum(c.marks) desc) rn
      from students s
      inner join crs_regd c on s.rollno=c.crs_rollno
      inner join depts d on d.deptcode=s.deptcode
      group by s.name,d.deptname) x
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
select a.name, b.deptname,c.marks 
from students a
     , crs_regd b
     , depts c
where a.rollno = b.crs_rollno 
and a.deptcode = c.deptcode 
and(c.deptname,b.marks) in (select do.deptname, max(x.marks) 
                            from students so
                            inner join depts do
                            on do.deptcode=so.deptcode
                           inner join (select s.name as name
                                              , d.deptname as deptname
                                              , sum(c.marks) as marks 
                                      from students s
                                        inner join crs_regd c
                                        on s.rollno=c.crs_rollno
                                        inner join depts d
                                        on d.deptcode=s.deptcode
                                       group by s.name,d.deptname) x
                         on x.name=so.name 
                         and x.deptname=do.deptname 
                         group by do.deptname
     )
```

Inner/Sub query will fetch the course name and max marks and the outer query gets the corresponding name of the student.

try and let know if you got the desired result

Comment: This will not work because `b.marks` doesn't necessary be present in the sub query as the sub query returns the total marks. That's why only those department which have only one course(such as `English`) will be shown and record of `Computer Science` is not shown.

Comment: Your code mixes ANSI-89 (implicit) joins with ANSI-92 (explicit) joins. Different people have differing opinions over the choice of join syntax. But we all agree on one thing: **don't mix the two**. Choose one syntax and stick with it for the whole query.

Answer (score 0):

Dense_Rank() function would be helpful in this scenario:

```
 SELECT subquery.* 
 FROM (SELECT Student_Total_Marks.rollno,
              Student_Total_Marks.name, 
              Student_Total_Marks.deptcode, depts.deptname, 
              rank() over (partition by deptcode order by total_marks desc) Student_Rank
       FROM (SELECT Stud.rollno,
                    Stud.name,
                    Stud.deptcode, 
                    sum(course.marks) total_marks
             FROM students stud inner join course course on stud.rollno = course.crs_rollno
             GROUP BY stud.rollno,Stud.name,Stud.deptcode) Student_Total_Marks,
       dept dept
       WHERE Student_Total_Marks.deptcode = dept.deptname
       GROUP BY Student_Total_Marks.deptcode) subquery
 WHERE suquery.student_rank = 1
```